# Computing $\int \sqrt{x\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[4]{x\sqrt[5]{x\cdots}}}} \,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I've just read a post that has been put on hold.  The question was about computing
$$
\int_{ }^{ }\sqrt{x\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[4]{x\sqrt[5]{x \cdots}}}}\, \mathrm{d}x
$$
My attempt was to find explicitely the integrand hence I introduced the sequence
$$
a_1=1\ \text{ and }\ a_{n+1}=\left(xa_n\right)^{1/(n+1)}
$$
hence
$$
a_2=\sqrt{xa_1}=\sqrt{x}, \ a_3=\sqrt[3]{xa_2}=\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt{x}} \ \dots
$$
But the power is reversed, how can I ffind the corresponding $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ ?

Comment: Hint: $$x^{1/2}x^{1/6}x^{1/4!}x^{1/5!}\cdots=x^{e-2}$$

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

$\sqrt{x\sqrt[3]{x\sqrt[4]{x{...\sqrt[n]{x}}}}} = \sqrt{x} \cdot \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{x}} \cdot \sqrt{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[4]{x}}} \cdot... = \displaystyle{x^{\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k!}}}$.

Let $r = \displaystyle{{\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k!}}}$. So $\displaystyle{\int{x^rdx} = \frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1} + \mathcal{C}}$.

Comment: You must mean $r = e-2$.